# PowerBI - Get the Index of the First Occurance of a value in the column

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to return the Index of a first occurrence of a value in a column.

I would want to use the Calculated Column functionality in PowerBI.

For Example,

```
Input      Output
ASD           1
ASD           1
ASD           1
GEF           4
GEF           4
HIJ           6
GEF           4
```

This can be done in excel using a simple formula like,

```
MATCH(A2,A:A,0)-1
```

For PowerBI to understand Index, I have created a column called as Index on the Query editor and made the data look like,

```
Index Input      Output
 1     ASD           ?
 2     ASD           ?
 3     ASD           ?
 4     GEF           ?
 5     GEF           ?
 6     HIJ           ?
 7     GEF           ?
```

How to do this in PowerBI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I did this was to find the minimal index the corresponds to the `Input` value in the table:

```
Output = MINX(
              FILTER(TableName,
                     TableName[Input] = EARLIER(TableName[Input])),
              TableName[Index])
```

This takes the minimal index over the table, where `Input` matches the value of `Input` in the original (earlier) row context.